# Facebook app review can't generate page access token

Tags: facebook, messenger

My facebook app is currently under review, but when I setting up the webhook, app cannot generate the page access token.

Response:

> "Invalid Scopes: manage_pages, pages_messaging,
>   pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions. This
>   message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore
>   these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid
>   permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions"

Please suggest.

Comment: Response to what exactly? Please describe what exactly you did where, to get to this error message. What API version are you using? In v3.0, adding all four permissions you mentioned to the login dialog call does not give me any such error.

Comment: I just switch my app to live mode, but after i switch it to live mode, i can't generate page access token under Messenger->setting->Token Generation, However, when i switch it back to dev mode, i can generate page access token again

Comment: You need to submit your app for review, before you can use it in live mode.